# SparkR says it can't find function read.df

Tags: apache-spark, centos, redhat, sparkr

Just what the title says. Every time I fire up the SparkR shell on the RedHat machine I'm using and try to use the function read.df(), it says that it could not find that function. I'm using SparkR 2.0, if that helps.

To be more specific, here's what I tried to type:

`data <- read.df(sqlContext, "/path/to/the/file", "parquet")`

**Edit:** To clarify, here is the exact situation:

`> data <- df.read("valid/path/to/parquet/file", "parquet") 
Error: could not find function "df.read"`

Comment: Have you loaded the sparkR package?

Comment: I think so...it said it loaded successfully. Do you have any recommendations for how I can check to make sure everything is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem is, and figured I'd post it in case anyone else had a similar issue. Basically I opened the R shell, and ran `install.packages("devtools")`. This allowed me to install the sparkR package directly from github like this: `devtools::install_github("/apache/spark/R/pkg")`. That worked. There were some other little details, too, like using R's `setRepositories()` function to make sure I had all repos enabled to download `devtools`.

I had done all of that before, though. The real problem was threefold:

1. I incorrectly typed in the function. There is a lot of conflicting documentation about it from different versions (something I have noticed is kind of a trend with Spark-related endeavors; check for versions before trusting any documentation!). The correct syntax is `read.df("/path/to/file", "parquet")` where `"parquet"` can be json or whatever file type you're reading in.
2. I needed to attach the sparkR package after I opened the R shell!!! I'm really new to R and sparkR and honestly 99% of what I'm trying to do, so I didn't actually know that R didn't automatically load all available packages at the beginning of a session. Actually, it makes a lot of sense that it *doesn't.* So I had to type in `require("SparkR")` into the shell prompt before I could actually read in any dataframes. *(Note that the S in `"SparkR"` is capitalized; I think this could lead to some confusion since in all the googling and research and combing through APIs that I did to arrive at this solution, many times the s in SparkR was lowercase.)*
3. I didn't initialize a SparkSession. (Duh!) Once you require the SparkR package, this is the (mandatory) next step, or else you won't be able to do anything Spark-related. A session can be initialized by typing `sparkR.session()` into the R shell prompt. Note that for some reason, the s in `sparkR` is lowercase here! That is really confusing and I hope in future updates that inconsistency is fixed.

Now I'm able to read in any dataframes I want using the following syntax:

`data <- read.df("/valid/path/to/parquet/file", "parquet")`

Answer (score 0):

The sqlContext parameter is no longer required read.df("./examples/src/main/resources/people.parquet", "parquet")

Check this https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/read.df.html

Comment: I tried this already and still got the same result! Thanks though.

Comment: Can you please show the error screenshot and the code

Comment: Yes, I have included the exact error there. I will not post too much specific information because I want to keep my company's IP private.